# How to convert a 'datetime' column

Tags: pyspark

In my PySpark dataframe, I have a column 'TimeStamp' which is in DateTime format.  I want to covert that to 'Date' format and then use that in the 'GroupBy'.

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM `myTable`")
df.filter((df.somthing!="thing"))
df.withColumn('MyDate', col('Timestamp').cast('date')
df.groupBy('MyDate').count().show()
```

But I get this error:

```
 cannot resolve 'MyDate' given input columns:
```

Can you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time you do `df.` you are creating a new dataframe.
`df` was only initialized in your first line of code, so that dataframe object does not have the new column `MyDate`.
you can look at the `id()` of each object to see

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM `myTable`")
print(id(df))
print(id(df.filter(df.somthing!="thing")))
```

this is correct syntax to chain operations

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM myTable")
df = (df 
    .filter(df.somthing != "thing")
    .withColumn('MyDate', col('Timestamp').cast('date'))
    .groupBy('MyDate').count()
)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

UPDATE: this is a better way to write it

```
df = (
    spark.sql(
    """
        SELECT * 
        FROM myTable
    """)
    .filter(col("something") != "thing")
    .withColumn("MyDate", col("Timestamp").cast("date"))
    .groupBy("MyDate").count()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @iamdbot.  I have a related question. As I already have 'myTable' created. How can I create a `df` to select all columns from myTable without using '.sql' methond?

Comment: @n179911a you can just use `spark.read.table('myTable')`

Comment: @n179911a i updated my post with a better way to format it